# A combinatoric inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

How can I show that for every $0 < t < 1$,
$$
\frac{n (n - 1) \cdots (n - k + 1)}{(t + n - 1) (t + n - 2) \cdots (t + n - k)} \leq 1 + \frac{k}{t}
$$
where $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ and $k \in \{0, 1, \dots, n\}$?

Comment: Are you looking for an algebraic proof?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: Not necessarily. Any proof will do. The simpler the better.

Comment: if we go on it the easiest way we have 
$$
\frac{n (n - 1) \cdots (n - k + 1)}{(t + n - 1) (t + n - 2) \cdots (t + n - k)} \leq \left(\frac{n}{t+n-k}\right)^k 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to prove that
$$\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{n+1-j}{n+t-j}\leq\frac{t+k}{t}\tag{1}$$
but the LHS of $(1)$ is:
$$ G(n,k,t)=\frac{n!(n+t-k-1)!}{(n-k)!(n+t-1)!}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+t-k)}{\Gamma(n+t)\Gamma(n+1-k)}\tag{2}$$
that is a log-convex and positive function over $(0,1)$ by the Bohr-Mollerup theorem or the identity:
$$\frac{d}{dz}\log\Gamma(z+1)=\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z}{n(n+z)}.\tag{3}$$
Log-convexity plus positivity implies convexity, hence for any $t\in(0,1)$ we have:
$$ G(n,k,t) \leq t\, G(n,k,1) + (1-t)\, G(n,k,0) = t + (1-t)\frac{n}{n-k}=\frac{n-kt}{n-k}\tag{4}$$
that is way stronger than needed.

Comment: Thank you. It's a lovely proof. It can be simplified even further by proving directly that $\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{n+1-j}{n+t-j}$ is log-convex and then jumping directly to the sentence following (3).